# Twilio is unable to play .mp3 and .wav files

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Unfortunately, when I am using Twilio voice message, it does not play the message and some noise gets to play instead. I used the mime-types supported by Twilio, too.

```
      var response = new VoiceResponse();
                var call = Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.CallResource.Read(parentCallSid: callSid).ToList();
                if (call[0].Status.ToString() == "in-progress")
                {
                    VoiceMail voiceMail = voiceMailService.GetVoiceMailByVoiceMailId(voiceMailId);
                    if (voiceMail != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(voiceMail.RecordUrl))
                    {
                        response.Play(url: new Uri(voiceMail.RecordUrl));
                        response.Hangup();
                    }
                    Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.CallResource.Update(new Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.UpdateCallOptions(call[0].Sid) { Twiml = response.ToString() });
                    status = true;
```

can you please help

Comment: What language are you using here? And can you share more of the context around the code you already included? How are you responding to the webhook?

Comment: we are using C# or if you have any queries just ping me

Comment: Can you share more context around that code? How are you responding to the webhook?

Comment: var response = new VoiceResponse();
                    
                        
                            response.Play(url: new Uri("https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3"));
                            response.Hangup();

Comment: Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.CallResource.Update(new Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.UpdateCallOptions(call[0].Sid) { Twiml = response.ToString() });

Comment: you need to more info or enough

Comment: It's really hard to read that in comments. Can you edit your original question and provide the entire code that responds to the incoming HTTP request, please?

Comment: hi philnash ,just now edit the content

Comment: Ok, that helps a bit more. So you're updating a call using the REST API with some TwiML. Your code looks quite different to [the example here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-update-a-call-in-progress-with-twiml&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x), could you try something like that? Do you get errors in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger) and can you share them?

Comment: Tiwlio it show this error Invalid Content-Type

Comment: hi can i chat for this issue

Comment: It seems you are receiving a webhook request here, but you are using the REST API to update the call. It is much easier to send the TwiML back as a response to the incoming request. If you are getting an invalid Content-Type, you should set the Content-Type in your response to `text/xml`.

Comment: Twilio was unable to fetch content from: http://lmvmdevstorage.blob.core.windows.net/lmvmdevstorage/VoiceMails/Recordings/RE80d157fb053f49878e9994a772fbf44f
Error: Empty/Invalid Response from Remote Host lmvmdevstorage.blob.core.windows.net
Account SID: AC1efe6ea658294794f955cc04e657973d
SID: CA912cbd7768a428a7cced5f6ea830a203
Request ID: 6f256e65-1354-423a-8413-c2181b2b2a61
Remote Host: lmvmdevstorage.blob.core.windows.net
Request Method: GET
Request URI: http://lmvmdevstorage.blob.core.windows.net/lmvmdevstorage/VoiceMails/Recordings/RE80d157fb053f49878e9994a772fbf44f

Comment: hi philnash its showing this error in twilio debugger

Comment: So Twilio is unable to fetch the content from that URL. Are you able to fetch the content you expect from that URL? I clicked on it and got a variety of error messages.

Comment: yes when i browseing its working fine and i think your browse only http and your check https its working

Comment: I checked https and got a mime type error.

Comment: I know is there any solution?

Comment: You need to fix whatever is serving your audio files, so that a file is successfully served to Twilio.

Comment: OK Twilio Call Success it still not working voice message

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean now. What is succeeding and what is failing?

Comment: Hi Philnash, one more issue  when my web app network failed  in that scenario we are calling disconnect but still agent ringing the call

Comment: https://lmvmdevstorage.blob.core.windows.net/lmvmdevstorage/VoiceMails/Recordings/RE1790b2ed745744f79924c631f62f9e79.ulaw

Comment: above one success but it play some nosie and one more thing can you browse above url its downloading but when i am browseing directly play voice message with out downloading

Comment: I just downloaded that audio file and it appears to be about 0.2s of white noise. How are you creating these audio files?

Comment: using MediaRecorder

Comment: Can you please explain in more depth. What MediaRecorder? Please describe as much as you can so that I can understand what you are doing and try to help.

Comment: in that are you hearing any voice message like Hi?

Comment: I hear static. I need to know more about how you are recording this audio. Please describe what you are doing in detail.

Comment: mediarecorder is angualr libary in this they have some basic  like start and stop recordering methods avaialbe

Comment: It's an Angular library? So you are recording this file in the client-side? How are you getting a ulaw file out of that?

Comment: navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
        .then(_stream => {
          this.isRecord = true;
          this.stream = _stream;
          this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream);
          this.recorder.ondataavailable = e => {
            console.log("data-available");
            this.chunks.push(e.data);
            console.log(this.recorder.state);
            if (this.recorder.state == 'inactive') {
              this.createDownloadLink();
              this.fileUploaded = true;
              this.fileReplaced = true;
            }

Comment: ya exactly in that one they gave audio/webm but its not support twilio so i can change content-type audio/ulaw and then passing to blob storage account

Comment: Ah, you are using the web [`MediaRecorder` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder). That outputs audio files in the webm format, not ulaw, like the extension on the file you shared above. Change the extension to .webm and you will be able to play the file.

Comment: You didn't change the content-type, you changed the extension.

Comment: like below manner i pass

Comment: this.audioFile = new File([this.audioBlob],  "recording.ulaw", { 'type': 'audio/ulaw' });

Comment: i will try that one also its not working

Comment: The audioBlob in that code is a webm file. You can tell it that it's ulaw, but that doesn't convert it, you just end up with a webm file with a .ulaw extension. That's why you can't hear anything when you play it.

Comment: ok just tell me what am doing now?

Comment: dont change exetenson name

Comment: send me the format

Comment: You need to save the files as webm files, then convert them somehow to a format that Twilio can play (like mp3, wav or ulaw). You will need to convert them on the server-side. What language are you using on the server-side?

Comment: C# how can i change server side is there any reference link?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From the comments, we established that you are creating audio files using the web's [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) and trying to play those files back through Twilio.

The MediaRecorder API is only capable of creating webm files. Saving those files with a different mime type/extension does not convert them to that other format.

The [Twilio `<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play) element can only play files in the following formats: mp3, wav, aiff, gsm, and ulaw.

If you want to use the audio you record in the browser you will need to convert the webm files to one of those formats. You could do this in the browser with a site like [Cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com/webm-to-mp3). That is not very scalable though, so you likely want to automate this conversion in your own code.

You could use a third party service, like [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/audio_transformations), to perform these audio transformations. There is [example code in the Cloudinary docs](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/audio_transformations) for this.

Alternatively you could convert these files on your own server. I am not a C# developer, so I can't give you a good example here. But you likely want to rely on an underlying media library, like [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) or [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/). There are likely libraries to wrap these in C# and tutorials for how to use them, but I can't help any further with that.

Comment: ok thank you so much philnash for your kind information

Answer (score -1):

Kindly use the method bellow

PHP laravel

```
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;
$response = new VoiceResponse();
$response->play(http://www.yourwebsite.com/dir/welcome_mp3);
echo $response;
exit;
```

will return this code on your webhooks can play an mp3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play loop="10">https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

Comment: NO , It is a PHP cod, it make TWML code in XML , Twilio use TWML code to play the 
                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                        Mp3.    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play loop="10">https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3</Play>
</Response>

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @Nikhilmn. I think the issue is a bit deeper than just producing the TwiML. We have some audio encoding to overcome.

Comment: I am sorry that you cant achieve play mp3 let me know where you stuck I am happy to help you.  The callback URL mist return as the same code. https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play Go through the link. will be helpful full, free to ask any Twilio-related doubt.